# Shifting groups of data in a data frame by varying amounts

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a bit of a weird question, so much so I wasn't sure how to word it in the title. Hopefully my title wasn't too nebulous.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
         date group      var
1  2021-01-01     a 2.764778
2  2021-01-02     a 4.892141
3  2021-01-03     a 2.486112
4  2021-01-04     a 1.739975
5  2021-01-05     a 7.659880
6  2021-01-01     b 3.392597
7  2021-01-02     b 1.779345
8  2021-01-03     b 5.398855
9  2021-01-04     b 5.775767
10 2021-01-05     b 6.149879
11 2021-01-01     c 4.158317
12 2021-01-02     c 3.900402
13 2021-01-03     c 1.472088
14 2021-01-04     c 4.026028
15 2021-01-05     c 3.841590
16 2021-01-01     d 3.259498
17 2021-01-02     d 5.705856
18 2021-01-03     d 4.753199
19 2021-01-04     d 3.386846
20 2021-01-05     d 4.201073
```

I have to create a new variable that has each group's var values shifted, but each group is shifted by a different amount. The data is contained in another DF that looks like this:

```
  group shiftnum
1     a        1
2     b        3
3     c        2
4     d        3
```

Such that there would be a new var.shift column with a's values shifted forward 1, b's values shifted 3 and so on.

I'm still fairly new to all of this and the best I could come up with is a piece of code like this using mutate, but obviously it doesn't work.

```
df <- df %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(var.shift = shift(var, shift.values[which(shift.values$group == group), 2])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The actual data has 60+ groups and the shiftnum values change periodically and I'm at a loss how to get what I need done accomplished.

Here is the code to reproduce the minimum example:

```
df <- data.frame(date = rep(as.Date("2021-01-01") + 0:4, 4),
                 group = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 5), rep("d", 5)),
                 var = rnorm(20, 4, 2))

shift.values <- data.frame(group = c(letters[1:4]), shiftnum = c(1, 3, 2, 3))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the two dataframes and shift each `var` by the corresponding `shiftnum` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(shift.values, by = 'group') %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(var.shift = lag(var, first(shiftnum))) %>%
  ungroup()

#   date       group   var shiftnum var.shift
#   <date>     <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 2021-01-01 a     3.66         1    NA    
# 2 2021-01-02 a     5.06         1     3.66 
# 3 2021-01-03 a     2.07         1     5.06 
# 4 2021-01-04 a     7.12         1     2.07 
# 5 2021-01-05 a     0.833        1     7.12 
# 6 2021-01-01 b     2.88         3    NA    
# 7 2021-01-02 b     4.39         3    NA    
# 8 2021-01-03 b     6.58         3    NA    
# 9 2021-01-04 b     1.47         3     2.88 
#10 2021-01-05 b     2.66         3     4.39 
#11 2021-01-01 c     2.70         2    NA    
#12 2021-01-02 c     2.47         2    NA    
#13 2021-01-03 c     2.35         2     2.70 
#14 2021-01-04 c     2.95         2     2.47 
#15 2021-01-05 c     3.96         2     2.35 
#16 2021-01-01 d     4.58         3    NA    
#17 2021-01-02 d     0.182        3    NA    
#18 2021-01-03 d     1.39         3    NA    
#19 2021-01-04 d     1.93         3     4.58 
#20 2021-01-05 d     1.73         3     0.182
```

Remove the `shiftnum` column from the output if not needed by adding  `%>% select(-shiftnum)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had been racking my brain on how to sidestep this problem and was having no luck.